# php custom error handler how to print error in production?

Tags: php, ajax, json, error-handling

I have an interface calling some php function by ajax.

There is an uncatched error that I have only in production. Due I make estensive use of getJson data exchange , I needed to silent errors and warnings with a custom php error handler.

The problem is that anyway when code generates an error in production I wish to print it out to the user, to understand where the problem is. My code is :

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{

switch ($errno) {
case E_ERROR:
    case E_USER_ERROR:
    $error= "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
    $error.= "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
    $error.= ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
    $error.= "Aborting...<br />\n";
    if(isAjaxCalling()){
        $_SESSION['Errors']['Errors'][]=$error;
    }

    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('error_reporting','E_ALL');
    echo $error;
    exit(1);
    break;
case E_WARNING:
case E_USER_WARNING:
```

....

}

Comment: 1 - I think you need to remove  ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('error_reporting','E_ALL');
2 - Why don't save the $error in a txt file or send it by email ?

Comment: E_ALL is constant, don't wrap it in quotes. It becomes 0 then => no error reporting.

Comment: E_ALL works also as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to let know the ajax handler on the client side that the returned value is in fact an error message, best to do it with status header:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal server error");
```

Then either globaly, or individualy per ajax request, set function that will handle the error. In jQuery, how to do it globaly: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/ or individualy set 'error' option of ajax request.

Comment: sorry but the problem is that server doesn't print the error, in the link it's how it's being managed by jquery on client?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's now printed with this mod:

```
case E_ERROR:
case E_USER_ERROR:
$error= "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
$error.= "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
$error.= ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
$error.= "Aborting...<br />\n";
if(isAjaxCalling()){
    $_SESSION['Errors']['Errors'][]=$error;
}

exit( $error);
break;
```